# Можно ли вытянуть sql файл, редактировать его и импортировать в базу одним скриптом?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, ftp

Есть следующая ситуация: каждый день на фтп выгружается база сайта "А" в формате .sql. После чего вручную из нее выбираются две нужные таблицы, отфильтровуются старые значения (которые уже есть в базе "Б") и вручную импортируются в базу "Б". Можно ли автоматизировать этот процесс? Если да, то в какую сторону смотреть и с помощью чего это вообще можно сделать? Есть подозрения что все можно сделать с помощью PHP, но хотелось бы услышать реально ли это.

Answer (score 1):

PHP тут не нужен , если базы идентичны то нужен простой BASH на 3 строчки

1. Создайте базу TMP на том же сервере с тем же пользователем что и
   основная база
2. Загружаете в нее дамп сайта

   **mysql -uuser -ppass TMP < /tmp/databasename.sql**
3. Выбираем из базы TMP из нужной таблицы те записи которых нет в основной базе и тут же вставляем

   **INSERT INTO DB1.table1**

   **SELECT * FROM TMP.table1 B WHERE B.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM DB1.table1);**
4. По аналогии делаем с другими таблицами
5. Добавляем задание в крон на ежедневное обновление данных и забываем.

Comment: К базе "А" нет доступа. Их выгружает владелец базы "А"  на фтп сервера, где находится база "Б", в sql формате. И вот мне надо взять этот файл с фтп, вытянуть оттуда две таблицы, отсеять данные которые уже есть в базе "Б" и импортировать в базу "Б".

Comment: Ну так в чем не то мое решение , у Вас есть ftp берете файл , заливаете в базу C , далее юзаете ее средствами SQL .

Answer (score 0):

Да, на php такое возможно.

Вы же сами очень хорошо описали логику, так и следуйте ей же :)

Вам нужно идти по пути:
Начать с работы с файлами на php
Потом понять по каким критериям выдёргивать нужные таблицы (полагаю, регуляркой)
И экспортировать стандартными средствами работы с бд (например, PDO)

Comment: "Потом понять по каким критериям выдёргивать нужные таблицы (полагаю, регуляркой)".

Comment: Критерии я могу выделить, но не представляю как редактировать документ в формате sql, с помощью кода php.

Comment: @ВикторБаранник, так же, как и с любым другим файлом (например .txt)